# Sampling rate of Android accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sample

I want a sampling frequency of 20Hz, i.e. 20 samples/second. But, my phone accelerometer has sampling frequency of only 17Hz in SENSOR_DELAY_GAME. Is there any way to give delay by program to get 20 samples?

Answer (score 1):

A delay would not fit, you actualy want a faster sampling rate. You can either keep the rate as it is or interpolate your samples to create 20 values out of 17.

Comment: How can I interpolate the samples from android accelerometer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation. But you better use your 17 per second as is. Interpolation is not so hard, but not trivial, and for 3 values I really wonder how it could change that much your app liability. It's a 15% error. Can you live with that ?